# UseEffect not re-rendering on use state object property change

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks

I have a component that fetches data from an API and displays it in a select box. When the select box is changed, it updates a property inside the state. When this is done, I want to run a different useEffect which fetches more values from the API based on the selected item.

```
// State for dropdown options
const [categories, setCategories] = useState<DropdownItemProps[]>([]);

// State for form
const [category] = useState<CategoryInstance>({
    id: "",
    number: 1,
    sponsor: "",
    logo: "",
    permit: "",
    bumpSpot: 128,
    raceEventId: "670d34d5-134b-4408-91bd-691f8c4b62d2",
    categoryId: "",
    configurationId: "",
    category: null,
    configuration: null,
    raceEvent: null,
    ladder: null,
    entryList: [],
    rounds: [],
});

// UseEffect 1, fetch dropdown items on load
useEffect(() => {
    console.log("Use effect 1");
    let c: DropdownItemProps[] = [];
    categoryStore.loadCategories().then(() => {
        categoryStore.categories.forEach((x) =>
            c.push({
                key: x.id,
                value: x.id,
                text: x.name,
            })
        );
        setCategories(c);
    });
}, [categoryStore]);

// UseEffect 2, fetch more items
useEffect(() => {
    console.log("Use effect 2");
    console.log(`ID: ${category.categoryId}`);
}, [category.categoryId]);
```

From my understanding, when the category.categoryId changes value, it should cause the UseEffect to print out the information. But this isn't happening.

[image]

```
<SelectInput
name='categoryId'
placeholder='Category'
label='Category'
options={categories}
search
/>
```

Select Input

```
import { useField } from "formik";
import { DropdownItemProps, Form, Label, Select } from "semantic-ui-react";

interface Props {
    placeholder: string;
    name: string;
    type?: string;
    label?: string;
    options: DropdownItemProps[];
    search: boolean;
}

export default function SelectInput(props: Props) {
    const [field, meta, helpers] = useField(props.name);
    return (
        <Form.Field error={meta.touched && !!meta.error}>
            <label>{props.label}</label>
            <Select
                clearable
                options={props.options}
                value={field.value || null}
                onChange={(event, data) => helpers.setValue(data.value)}
                onBlur={() => helpers.setTouched(true)}
                placeholder={props.placeholder}
                search={props.search}
            />
            {meta.touched && meta.error ? (
                <Label basic color='red'>
                    {meta.error}
                </Label>
            ) : null}
        </Form.Field>
    );
}
```

Any help would great,
Thanks.

Comment: `category.id` is the same so nothing reloads

Comment: React will not detect any direct object mutations. Like that is the reason why `useState` returns `setXXX` function as second item in the array, which you ignore currently. After the `category` is updated completely (reference to this object is changed) - this `useEffect` will wake up and compare `categoryId` of this object.

Comment: @Konrad Its `category.categoryId` not `category.id`

Comment: You never change your state, so your effects can't trigger. You can't modify state like that in react

Comment: https://dev.to/aileenr/til-you-can-watch-for-nested-properties-changing-in-react-s-useeffect-hook-26nj
This seems to contradict you both

Comment: You can watch for changes, but your component didn't rerender so it doesn't know it changed.

Comment: We didnt say you cant "watch for nested props changes", we are saying you cant trigger an update and notify React about something changed without calling a setState function in your case. If you are watching for nested props - you still need the top level object to be marked as changed for React. With setState function.

Comment: I was thinking, category  `const [category] = useState`  has a setter right, can we see the code in the select event handler

Comment: @Azzy I've added the code but it gets a little complicated as it uses formik

Comment: @SergeySosunov Whats the point in watching for nested properties if you cant re-render off them changing?

Comment: The point is to trigger a hook when 1) entire object is changed AND 2) an exact field is changed. But the root level object needs to be changed anyway. And if you add another hook that will watch for `id`, for example, in its dependency array - it will be called only if `id` is changed AND top level object is changed also. Ask, if something is not clear

Comment: Could [useFormik](https://formik.org/docs/api/useFormikContext) help you to detect the changes in the select form value